# Why redshift does not have entry for csv file in stl_load_commits ??

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift

Even though I know aws has mentioned on their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_COMMITS.html) that csv is more like txt file for them. But why there is no entry for CSV file.

For example:
If I am running a query like:

```
COPY "systemtable"  FROM 's3://test/example.txt' <credentials>  IGNOREHEADER 1  delimiter as ','
```

then its creating entry in stl_load_commits, which I can query by:

```
select query, curtime as updated from stl_load_commits where query = pg_last_copy_id();
```

But, in same way when I am tryig with:

```
COPY "systemtable"  FROM 's3://test/example.csv' 
<credentials>  IGNOREHEADER 1  delimiter as ','   format csv;
```

then return from

```
select query, curtime as updated from stl_load_commits where query = pg_last_copy_id();
```

is blank, Why aws does not create entry for csv ?

This is the first part of the question. Secondly, there must be some way through which we can check the status of the loaded file?
How can we check if the file has successfully loaded in DB if the file is of type csv?

Answer (score 0):

The format of the file does not affect the visibility of success or error information in system tables.

When you run `COPY` it returns confirmation of success and a count of rows loaded. Some SQL clients may not return this information to you but here's what it looks like using `psql`:

```
COPY public.web_sales from 's3://my-files/csv/web_sales/' 
FORMAT CSV 
GZIP 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::01234567890:role/redshift-cluster'
;
-- INFO:  Load into table 'web_sales' completed, 72001237 record(s) loaded successfully.
-- COPY
```

If the load succeeded you can see the files in `stl_load_commits`:

```
 SELECT query, TRIM(file_format) format, TRIM(filename) file_name, lines, errors FROM stl_load_commits WHERE query = pg_last_copy_id();
  query  | format |                 file_name                   |  lines  | errors
---------+--------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------
 1928751 | Text   | s3://my-files/csv/web_sales/0000_part_03.gz | 3053206 |     -1
 1928751 | Text   | s3://my-files/csv/web_sales/0000_part_01.gz | 3053285 |     -1
```

If the load fails you should get an error. Here's an example error (note the table I try to load):

```
COPY public.store_sales from 's3://my-files/csv/web_sales/' 
FORMAT CSV 
GZIP 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::01234567890:role/redshift-cluster'
;
--ERROR:  Load into table 'store_sales' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.
```

You can see the error details in `stl_load_errors`.

```
SELECT query, TRIM(filename) file_name, TRIM(colname) "column", line_number line, TRIM(err_reason) err_reason FROM stl_load_errors where query = pg_last_copy_id();
  query  |      file_name         |      column       | line |       err_reason
---------+------------------------+-------------------+------+---------------------------
 1928961 | s3://…/0000_part_01.gz | ss_wholesale_cost |    1 | Overflow for NUMERIC(7,2)
 1928961 | s3://…/0000_part_02.gz | ss_wholesale_cost |    1 | Overflow for NUMERIC(7,2)
```

Comment: Have you tried with single large csv file ? Because in case of single file its not creating entry for it.

Comment: Have you tried with `psql` to be sure any error are visible? Can you query the data in the table? Is it successfully loaded?

Comment: Yes, I have tried in stl_load_errors, there is no entry for this query and all the data is successfully inserted into the destination table.

Comment: Ok, please send me a private message on the AWS Redshift forum (joeharris76-AWS) with your cluster name and region so we can look into it. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=155